# Soft bodies bouncing with collision

Tags: objects, physics, soft-body

I am trying to get soft body objects to interact with each other as if they were real world, rubbery objects.

An example of the type of material I am trying to create can be seen in David McLeod's work (who uses C4D):

https://vimeo.com/131654511

When I try to make soft body objects interact, they usually merge with each other:

[image: animated gif of softbody objects intersecting]

or fly around like crazy:

[image: animated gif of softbody objects bouncing off]

But although I have tried many different settings, I couldn't get the soft bodies to bounce off each other and interact properly as they would in real life.

How could I achieve that?

Here is a .blend file that I'm having the problem with:

[image]

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload. The links on pasteall.org have a time limit

Comment: Thanks! I love blend-exchange! But the file is 9mb, exceeds limit of blend-exchange; do you have another suggestion?

Comment: 10mb is way under the file limit for blend exchange...

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was thinking about another scene for which I had a large file I think... I've edited the question with a blend-exchange link, hopefully it'll help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add to those soft bodies the "collision" physics type too, like :

[image: Physics panel]

It's required for softbody physics found another softbody type like obstacles. That's will bring you a new panel called "Collision". Inside "Collision" panel there is controls for softbody types if you want tweak. Usually the default values works nice.

Like you already have the scene filled with your falling men, and you require add that physics to everyone,  there is an easy way to archive this :

- You must switch on the addon "Copy Attributes menu" (it comes with the basic blender). This activate a really useful copy menu.
- Select all your softbody man except the last one with your collision  and softbody physics. (you can try to use "A" key and quit rest objects from scene using "Shift" for quit/add objects from your selection)
- Select that last one (usually this is for Blender like select "the parent")
- Then press "Control + C" and select "Copy modifiers" from menu. That will copy the modifiers (in this case, physics type) from that last one to all another selected ones.